# Flask shows list of email as [email protected] when the page is loading

Tags: python, flask, datatable

This is not much of an error. I am filtering a dataframe and creating a table with username and email address and displaying it in a table. The dataframe has about 4000-5000 rows. When I load this page, it takes like 2-3 sec to render this page. And in this 2-3 sec , I see all the email address as [email protected]. I was curious as to why this happens. (This page also has a bunch of other computational expensive things going on)

[image]

Thanks in advance to anyone who can explain this to me!

Browser: Google Chrome

Using Datatables to display the table in jinja.

Comment: This is not normal. What libraries are involved here?

Comment: It seems like it's a FOUC but I'm curious about what library is hiding the email that you then go on to display

Comment: @snakecharmerb Google Chrome

Comment: @roganjosh I am using datatable to display the table. https://datatables.net/

Comment: @user9361871 Kindly edit your Question to include all relevant information.

Comment: @user9361871 It was done already.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a Datatables (client-side Javascript) thing.

I get exactly the same issue, while large tables are initially loading.

The reason I believe that it's Datatables rather than Chrome is that I get exactly the same issue in Safari.

And it can't be Flask, since I get the same if I output a large table in PHP :-)